# Brackets correctly nested code excercise

Tags: php, stack

I solved this excercise to check if brackets are correctly nested, https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/7-stacks_and_queues/brackets/ 
but it fails in some test and the correctness is only 33%.
I cannot understand where is the problem in my code.

```
function solution($S) {

// write your code in PHP7.0
$string = str_split($S);
$stack = [];

foreach($string as $value){

    switch ($value) {   
        case '{':
            array_push($stack,$value);
        break;
        case '[':
            array_push($stack,$value);
        break;
        case '(':
            array_push($stack,$value);
        break;
        case '}':
            if(array_pop($stack) !== '{'){return 0;};
        break;
        case ']':
            if(array_pop($stack) !== '['){return 0;};
        break;
        case ')':
           if(array_pop($stack) !== '('){return 0;};
        break;
     }
  }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You don't need a `;` after your closing `}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just insert the following line before your `return 1`

```
if (sizeof($stack) != 0) return 0;
```

You forgot that all brackets in your stack had to be reduced for a correct bracket-string.